# can't get location from network isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) always false

Tags: android, android-gps

I am able to get location when GPS is on, but can't get location when it's off.
I am trying to get the location from NETWORK_PROVIDER but it doesn't work.
also tried using FusedLocationApi but it is always null.

I use this permission in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

is always false.

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: NETWORK_PROVIDER  not properly work in Buildings and underground Area, you have to use google play services.

Comment: you have to enable gps, otherwise you always get null

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel what about the last known location ? can i get it when gps is off ?

Comment: Hey, try my answer please

Comment: `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);`
if is False you have Enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your permissions to use NetWork Provider:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: @Maximtoyberman try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` to your permissions

Comment: @Maximtoyberman I edited the answer again and this should work for you